# WebSocketConnectionClosedException error Python 3.5

Tags: python, websocket

I've received the following error in my script on Websocket whilst trying to stream.

raise WebSocketConnectionClosedException("socket is already closed.")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: socket is already closed.

I tried to code an exception to catch it and restart the websocket:

```
    except WebSocketConnectionClosedException as e:
        ws = opensocket()
        websocket_open = True
        data = "WebSocketConnectionClosedException trying to restart stream"
        send_email(data,recipient)
        print(e)
```

However, when I run it now, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1668, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Bev/Documents/python_work/bot/l_stream2_3.py", line 1117, in 
    except WebSocketConnectionClosedException as e:
NameError: name 'WebSocketConnectionClosedException' is not defined

Question 1 : How do i define the error in order for the exception to catch the error

Question 2: Are there perhaps a better way to restart the socket if the host closes the connection, or if the stream dies?

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out.

```
import websocket

#<Code>

except websocket.WebSocketConnectionClosedException as e:
    print('This caught the exception')
```

Answer (score 0):

Think the proper way will be

```
from websocket import create_connection
from websocket._exceptions import WebSocketConnectionClosedException

ws=create_connection("wss://url")
while True:
    try:
        ws.recv()
    except WebSocketConnectionClosedException as e:
        #Triggered when connection is closed by server
        #Handle exception
```

Some common ways to handle will be to place the above in a function and recall that function when the exception is triggered. However it is better to follow the example here https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client if the connection is going to be long lived